# String concatenation inside my C-Lua hybrid program

Tags: c, lua

I can't figure out why this is happening, but it is, and it's weird. I'm brewing up a server to learn more about socket programming and the C-Lua API as well, and it works perfectly fine except for one (not-so-minor) hiccup.

So far, all it does is accept connections, and check for readable connections, then reads from them. It passes what it read to a Lua function in a Lua state specific to that connection, which then echoes it back to the client (as well as printing it out for the server).

For some reason, string concatenation is behaving really strangely. I can't reproduce it in a simple test program, so I don't know what's causing it. Basically, here's my lua/state.lua file:

```
function OnRead(...)
    local s = table.concat({...})
    print(s)
    s = 'You sent the string: "' .. s .. '" and then some stuff at the end.'
    print(s)
    send(s)
end
```

So, as you can see, pretty simple. The first print(s) will work fine. However, once I concatenate, the stuff at the end (i.e, the " and then some stuff at the end.) will get written over the start of the string! So if the input is the string "Hello World." then s won't become:

```
You sent the string: "Hello World." and then some stuff at the end.
```

but rather:

```
"and then some stuff at the end.d.
```

And I can't for the life of my figure out why it's doing this! It's a problem specific to the following code, as I can't reproduce it in a small simple program, but I don't know what could cause the Lua script to so strangely misbehave.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 5000

#define READ_OVERFLOW_SIZE_LIMIT 4098 /* maximum socket line length */
#define READ_BUFFER_SIZE 4098
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define SHORT_BUFFER_SIZE 64


#define STATE_LUA_FILE "lua/state.lua"
/* L_ prefix for Lua registry table keys */
#define L_CONNFD "server_connfd"
/* G_ prefix for Lua global table keys */
#define G_ONREAD_HANDLER "OnRead"

typedef struct node_t {
    struct node_t *next;
    struct node_t *prev;
    int value;
    lua_State *state;
} ll_conn_t;


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Appends a connection tuple to a linked list. Returns 0 on success, or a -1
 *  on error.
 *  If the connfd value is already present in the linked list, it will error.
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int ll_conn_append(ll_conn_t *list, int value, lua_State *state)
{
    ll_conn_t *temp;
    for (temp = list; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next)
    {
        if (temp->next->value == value)
            return -1;
    }
    temp->next = (ll_conn_t *)malloc(sizeof(ll_conn_t));
    temp->next->prev = temp;
    temp->next->next = NULL;
    temp->next->value = value;
    temp->next->state = state;
    list->value++;
    return 0;
}   /*-----  end of function ll_conn_append  -----*/


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Creates a new linked list and returns a pointer to the new linked list.
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
ll_conn_t *ll_conn_create()
{
    ll_conn_t *list = (ll_conn_t *)malloc(sizeof(ll_conn_t));
    list->next = NULL;
    list->prev = NULL;
    list->value = 0;
    list->state = NULL;
    return list;
}   /*-----  end of function ll_conn_create  -----*/


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Iterates over a linked list and completely frees up its memory.
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void ll_conn_delete(ll_conn_t *list)
{
    ll_conn_t *temp;
    for (temp = list->next; temp != NULL; list = temp, temp = temp->next)
    {
        lua_close(list->state);
        free(list);
    }
}   /*-----  end of function ll_conn_delete  -----*/


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Searches for and removes the first occurrence of a specific connfd from a
 *  linked list. Returns a boolean which indicates whether the value was found.
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int ll_conn_remove(ll_conn_t *list, int value)
{
    ll_conn_t *iter, *temp;
    for (iter = list; iter->next != NULL; iter = iter->next)
    {
        temp = iter->next;
        if (temp->value == value)
        {
            iter->next = temp->next;
            if (temp->next != NULL)
                temp->next->prev = iter;
            lua_close(temp->state);
            free(temp);
            list->value--;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}   /*-----  end of function ll_conn_remove  -----*/


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * lua_CFunction
 * Takes a string argument, and writes that string to this Lua state's socket
 * connection.
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int luasend(lua_State *L)
{
    int connfd, success, length;
    lua_pushstring(L, L_CONNFD);
    lua_rawget(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
    connfd = (int)lua_tointegerx(L, -1, &success);
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    if (!success)
    {
        /* error! */
        lua_pushstring(L, "Socket connfd could not be converted to integer!");
        lua_error(L);
    }
    length = luaL_len(L, -1);
    write(connfd, lua_tostring(L, -1), length);
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    return 0;
}   /*-----  end of function luasend  -----*/


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Takes as input a connected socket file descriptor and builds a new Lua
 *  state for that socket.
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
lua_State *l_create_state(int connfd)
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_pushstring(L, L_CONNFD);
    lua_pushinteger(L, connfd);
    lua_rawset(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
    lua_register(L, "send", *luasend);
    luaL_dofile(L, STATE_LUA_FILE);
    return L;
}   /*-----  end of function l_create_state  -----*/


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Reads from the Lua state's connection, and calls the Lua handler for each
 *  line it encounters in the read buffer.
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void l_read_conn(lua_State *L, int connfd)
{
    static char buffer[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int count = 1, i, start, overflow_count = 0, overflow_size = 0, len;
    while (1)
    {
        ioctl(connfd, FIONREAD, &len);
        if (len == 0)
            break;
        count = read(connfd, buffer, READ_BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (count == -1)
        {
            /* TODO error handling */
            break;
        }
        if (count == 0)
        {
            /* EOF */
            break;
        }
        start = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (buffer[i] != '\n')
                continue;
            if (!overflow_count)
                lua_getglobal(L, G_ONREAD_HANDLER);
            /* We won't be passing newlines to the handler. Otherwise, it would
             * be 1 + i - start. */
            lua_pushlstring(L, buffer + start, i - start);
            lua_call(L, 1, 0);
            overflow_count = overflow_size = 0;
            start = i + 1;
        }
        /* If there's bits in the buffer that aren't terminated with a newline,
         * add it as overflow to the stack.
         * NOTE: THIS IS A REALLY BAD IDEA !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/
        if (start < count)
        {
            if (!overflow_count)
                lua_getglobal(L, G_ONREAD_HANDLER);
            lua_pushlstring(L, buffer + start, count - start);
            overflow_size += count - start;
            overflow_count++;
            /* let's include this check to make this a marginally less bad idea
             * in order to soothe my OCD worries */
            if (overflow_size >= READ_OVERFLOW_SIZE_LIMIT)
                break;
        }
    }
    if (overflow_count)
        lua_call(L, overflow_count, 0);
}   /*-----  end of function l_read_conn  -----*/


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0, maxfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, conn_addr;
    char sendBuff[BUFFER_SIZE];
    lua_State *L;
    fd_set fds;
    ll_conn_t *connections = ll_conn_create();
    /* iterators */
    ll_conn_t *temp;
    int n;
    unsigned int i, j;

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listenfd == -1)
    {
        /* TODO error handling */
    }
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', BUFFER_SIZE);

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == 0)
    {
        /* TODO error handling */
    }

    if (listen(listenfd, 10) == -1)
    {
        /* TODO error handling */
    }

    while (1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(listenfd, &fds);
        if (listenfd >= maxfd)
            maxfd = listenfd + 1;
        for (temp = connections->next; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
            FD_SET(temp->value, &fds);
        if ((n = select(maxfd, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL)) > 0)
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(listenfd, &fds))
            {
                i = sizeof(conn_addr);
                connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&conn_addr, &i);
                if (connfd < 0)
                {
                    /* TODO error handling */
                }
                L = l_create_state(connfd); /* create new state */
                if (ll_conn_append(connections, connfd, L) < 0)
                {
                    /* TODO error handling */
                }
                if (connfd >= maxfd)
                    maxfd = connfd + 1;
                printf("New connection from %s.\n",
                        inet_ntoa(conn_addr.sin_addr));
            }
            /* we do iteration this way so that we don't segfault!!! */
            for (temp = connections->next; temp != NULL;)
            {
                connfd = temp->value;
                L = temp->state;
                temp = temp->next;
                if (FD_ISSET(connfd, &fds))
                {
                    /* check connection status */
                    ioctl(connfd, FIONREAD, &j);
                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        /* the socket should now be removed! */
                        ll_conn_remove(connections, connfd);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* read from connection */
                        l_read_conn(L, connfd);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (n < 0)
        {
            /* TODO error handling */
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}       /*----------  end of function main  ----------*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your 's' contains line-feed symbol sent by telnet or whatever you use. Get one of trim implementations from http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringTrim and use `s = 'You sent the string: "' .. trim(s) .. '" and then some stuff at the end.'` or something like that.

Update: sorry about that, it is far more likely to be carriage return. But no matter, in view point of your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what did it.